# can i connect to an api after basic or digest authentication, in a google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to connect to an API which uses Basic or Digest Auth- so the user can use the extension fully, only after he has logged in to the API- the extension will send and receive messages through the API and perform actions based on responses sent by the API.

Is such authentication possible for a google chrome extension? Can i ask user to provide userid/password (or API key) through a popup HTML File which is part of the extension? Or do I have to open a new tab in Chrome itself and ask the user to authenticate through that...

Which is the best/ideal way to authenticate into a web based API from a Google Chrome extension... Any guides or how-to s would be very helpful for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use popup or a new tab authentication, either way is OK.